# Generating out of a C program: Component diagram, SYSML and SystemC

Tags: uml, systemc, rhapsody, sysml

I have a C project. It has been imported to Rhapsody 8.2. 
Now I want to generate:

1. Component diagram.
2. Structural diagram.
3. Dataflow.
4. UML
5. SystemC

How to do that?
Thanks in advance

Amnon

Comment: I don't know Rhapsody in detail, but I'd say: with a lot of manual work. C is not OO and thus you likely won't see much support.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a self-populating Object Model Diagram by ticking the 'Populate Diagram' tick box when you create it, then selecting the packages/classes to include.

I think the others will have to be created and populated manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported a 'C' program. I think you have used "Reverse Engineering" to do that.
As already mentioned in one of the answers: C is not OO so you have little chance to derive the information that you want to generate simply because that information is not in your your source code.
You have probably already noticed that there will be no Classes with attributes and operations in your model, just files with variables and functions.
I'm always surprised to see people's expectations to reverse engineering... RE is a so-called GIGO process: Garbage in- Garbage out. Don't listen to sales people that tell you that there are tools that can automatically document your code afterwards: There is no such thing possible.

Component diagram. - Have to made by Hand
Structural diagram. - you can right click on a function and choose "populate flowchart"

Dataflow. - There is no Dataflow diagram in UML

UML. - As already said, there is not enough information in your source code to convert your C to a readable UML diagram

SystemC - You have to add a lot of information to create System-C, as already stated above, please contact Sodius in France or the US, they can provide you with more information.

W.